# Сохранить обе версии файла после слияния (merge)

Tags: git

Есть ветка `master` и ветка `feature`. Ветка `feature` содержит некоторые новые файлы, которых нет в `master`, а также изменённую версию файла `main.cpp`. Все изменения были сделаны одним разработчиком. При обычном `merge` ветки `feature` в ветку `master` я без конфликтов получаю всё из `master` + новые файлы из `feature` + **файл main.cpp из `feature`**. Файл `main.cpp` из `master` теряется.

Пытался переименовать файл `main.cpp` в `main_master.cpp` перед слиянием в ветке `master`, но даже тогда в итоге получаю переименованный файл `main_master.cpp` с содержимым из ветки `feature`.

Как сделать так, чтобы в итоге сохранились оба файла?

Comment: скопировать main.cpp куда-то, выполнить слияние в мастер, добавить новую версию main.cpp, сделать коммит

Comment: @СергейКоновалов а явно описать своё поведение с помощью `git` можно?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5  вот такая вещь есть. git stash

Comment: "Файл main.cpp из master теряется" - почему теряется, как вы это понимаете?